Flutter VerticalDivider height calculation
In my project, I have a CustomScrollView containing SliverAppBar and SliverToBoxAdapter . Inside the SliverToBoxAdapter, I have two ListViews of variable length in a Row. I want to add VerticalDivider between them with the height of the max height of the listviews. Here, IntrinsicHeight inside CustomScrollView is showing errors and Container with height is not going well . Is there any proper way to calculate the VerticalDivider height in this scenerio ???
SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight - 200,
// also tried   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: _sections.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            // my lists body
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    VerticalDivider(
                      width: 1.0,
                      thickness: 1.0, 
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outine,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: _sections.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            // my lists body
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

